# offline application development for mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, offline

I am looking to develop an application whereby field staff can complete forms in an offline capacity (when onsite I`m assuming no internet connection) on an Apple or Android device and post the results to a web service when they are online.

I have been lead to understand that this is achievable using sharepoint or infopath.  I would personally prefer to use Cordova / HTML / Javascript forms.

My question is:  Is what I have been told correct?  Is it possible to achieve this goal using sharepoint and/or infopath?

Comment: HTML5 and javascript can be used to store to a local database on a mobile device, so I'm guessing many other technologies could as well.

Comment: Googling for something like `html5 offline forms` will turn up a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** Its possible to achieve this in a Cordova app.

I had similar requirements and did in a project.

**localStorage** features of **HTML5** can be used to store data in offline mode and once a device has detected internet connection then it can automatically send via a service call.

So features you need would be:

- localStorage - for offline storage
- Cordova [Network](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) plugin will be used to detect network status
- In case GPS (location lat/lng) is required then **geolocation** API will be used